# Unable to access API params with req.query in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, req.query

I'm trying to access params in an API Get Method in NextJS. I've consulted multiple docs, tutorials, etc and everything points to req.query for NextJS, but req.query is returning undefined regardless of what url I send in the Fetch request

Clien Code:
(including several test URLs, all print the same in console, all send the same req.url in server code, all show req.query Undefined)

```
 const getData = async () => {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParams.append("tourid", tourid); // tourid passed in via url params, works as expected 
    const testUrl = `/api/tour/?${queryParams.toString()}`;
    const testUrl2 = `/api/tour/?tourid=${tourid}`;
    const testUrl3 = "/api/tour/?tourid=130e18e7-fb51-43eb-a145-3e2b2301899e"; //hardcoded test

    await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setTourData(data);
      });
  };
```

Server Code:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log("Request URL:", req.url); // prints as expected in console
  console.log("Received query:", req.query); // prints Undefined

  const tourid = req.query.tourid as string; // error, req.query is undefined
  

  /*
      ///// DATABASE CODE HERE /////
  */
  return NextResponse.json("ok");
}
```

Comment: Hi rasputinsgoat, please go through the answer of the linked thread and let us know  :)